# How to check existence of NaN keyword in an array?

Tags: javascript, nan

I have following array

```
var arr = [7, 1, "abc", undefined, NaN];
```

but how can i check if the value in arr is a NaN ?

```
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

    // check if array value is false or NaN
    if (arr[i] === false || arr[i] === NaN) {
        // do something
    }

  }
```

any idea ? I tried `isNaN(arr[i])` function but it is also not working.

Comment: NaN is the only value in JS which is not equal to anything else, even itself. So NaN === NaN always returns false.

Comment: Try `Number.isNaN`

Comment: Use function isNaN(NaN), or isFinite(NaN) to obtain true / false if value is valid / not valid number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ECMAScript 6 you can use the Number.isNaN function:

```
var arr = [7, 1, "abc", undefined, NaN];

for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

    // check if array value is false or NaN
    if (arr[i] === false || Number.isNaN(arr[i])) {
        console.log("NaN found at place " + i);
    }

  }
```

If you need to work in ECMAScript 5 then the problem with the isNaN function is that it is checking to see if the value is able to be coerced into a number.  Instead you could use the odd property of the NaN value - it isn't equal to itself:

```
var arr = [7, 1, "abc", undefined, NaN];

for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

    // check if array value is false or NaN
    if (arr[i] === false || arr[i] != arr[i]) {
        console.log("NaN found at place " + i);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Now in ECMAScript 7, you could also do:
`arr.includes(NaN)`

Answer (score 4):

For me this is working??

```
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

    // check if array value is false or NaN
    if (arr[i] === false || Number.isNaN(arr[i]) ) {
        console.log("NaN");
    }

  }
```

Comment: same here :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKvYOO

Comment: This is returning all items that aren't a number, not all instances of NaN.  My interpretation of the question is that 'abc' and undefined are OK and we just want to find the NaN number - see my answer below for this

Comment: @smuff Thanks for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 3):

You could check the type (`typeof NaN === 'number'`) and with `isNaN` for a `NaN` value.

```js
var arr = [7, 1, "abc", undefined, NaN], i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'number' && isNaN(arr[i])) {
        console.log('Element ' + i + ' is NaN');
    }
}
```

Or [check if the value is unequal to itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN).

```js
var arr = [7, 1, "abc", undefined, NaN], i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] !== arr[i]) {
        console.log('Element ' + i + ' is NaN');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert the value toString. Then check `value == 'NaN'`

```
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

    // check if array value is false or NaN
    if (arr[i] === false || (arr[i] != undefined && typeof(arr[i]) == "number" && arr[i].toString() === 'NaN')) {
        // do something
    }

  }
```

Comment: This will run for the string 'NaN' also, rather than just the actual value NaN.  It would fire twice for the array [NaN, 'NaN']

Comment: We can check first `typeof` `NaN`. If `typeof(NaN) == "number"` then proceed, see my update. Well this is not a good idea. `Accepted` answer is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

isNan works for me:

```
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    // check if array value is false or NaN
    if (isNaN(arr[i])) {
        console.log("Not a number at index " + i + ": "+arr[i]);
    }
}
```

prints (in node.js):

```
Not a number at index 2: abc
Not a number at index 3: undefined
Not a number at index 4: NaN
```